# replace some random selection from String[]

Tags: java, grammar

I have something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class gramatica {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [] Vt = {"S","R","L"};
    String [] Vn = {"a","b","c","d","e","f"};

    String [] S = {

            "aS","bS","cR","dL"
    };

    String[] R = {
            "dL","e"
    };

    String []L = {

            "fL","eL","d"
    };
    System.out.println(S[0]);
    String random = (S[new Random().nextInt(S.length)]);
    String chop = (S[new Random().nextInt(S.length)]);

    System.out.println("S->"+random);
```

If, after making the random selection from S, and getting, for example "cR", I want to replace instead of "R" some random selection from String[] R, how should I go about that?
Example:
Look i start with S , then i get random from S and if i got cR i replace only R with random from R string array. S->cR->cdL (instead of R i put dL)

Comment: OK, first things first: this question is about Java, so tag is as such.

Comment: Yes, sorry this was from previous question .

Comment: The problem is that when its for example cR i dont know how to replace  just R .

Comment: I really didn't understand the problem... and I tried.

Comment: Look i start with S , then i get random from S and if i got cR i replace only R with random from R string array.

S->cR->cdL  (instead of R i put dL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class gramatica {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [] Vt = {"S","R","L"};
    String [] Vn = {"a","b","c","d","e","f"};

    String [] S = {

            "aS","bS","cR","dL"
    };

    String[] R = {
            "dL","e"
    };

    String []L = {

            "fL","eL","d"
    };
    //System.out.println(S[0]);
    String rule = "S";

    Random r = new Random();

    // Make a loop
    while(true) {
      if(rule.contains("S")) {
        rule = rule.replaceFirst("S", S[r.nextInt(S.length)]);
        continue;
      };
      if(rule.contains("R")) {
        rule = rule.replaceFirst("R", R[r.nextInt(R.length)]);
        continue;
      };
      if(rule.contains("L")) {
        rule = rule.replaceFirst("L", L[r.nextInt(L.length)]);
        continue;
      };

      // Nothing to change, break loop
      break;
    };

    // Now we got a random possible rule for S! :)
    System.out.println("S->"+rule);
  };
};
```

This code will generate a random possible string for your grammar. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your hellp ! This will be enought

Comment: So, please, click on "accept the answer" so I get some reputation here. =P